# Do Loops (with multiple rows of id's) with conditional statements?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, sas, do-loops

Please see my data below;

```
data finance;
  input id loan1 loan2 loan3 assets home$ type;
datalines;
1 93000 98000 45666 new 1
1 98000 45678 98765 67 old 2
1 55000 56764 435371 54 new 1
2 7000 6000 7547 57 new 1
4 67333 87444 98666 34 old 1
4 98000 68777 986465 23 new 1
5 4555 334 652 12 new 1
5 78999 98999 80000 34 new 1
5 889 989 676 3 new 1
;

data finance1;
set finance;
if loan1<80000 then conc'level1';
if loan2 <80000 and home='new' then borrowcap = 'high';
run;
```

I would like the following dataset, as you can see although there are multiple rows for each ID initially, if there was a level1 or high in any of those rows, I would like to capture that in the same row.

```
data finance;
input id conc$ borrowcap$;
datalines;
1 level1 high
2 level1 high
4 level1
5 level1 high
;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `assets` of the first data row missing? From data row `4 98000 68777 986465 23 new 1`, why ID 4 doesn't deserve `high`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `retain` statement, you can keep value from any row for each ID. Use `by` statement + `if last.var` statement, you can keep only one row for each ID.

```
data finance;
  input id loan1 loan2 loan3 assets home$ type;
datalines;
1 93000 98000 45666   . new 1
1 98000 45678 98765  67 old 2
1 55000 56764 435371 54 new 1
2 7000  6000  7547   57 new 1
4 67333 87444 98666  34 old 1
4 98000 68777 986465 23 new 1
5 4555  334   652    12 new 1
5 78999 98999 80000  34 new 1
5 889   989   676    3  new 1
;

data finance1;
  set finance;
  by id;

  retain conc borrowcap;
  length conc borrowcap $8.;
  if first.id then call missing(conc,borrowcap);
  if loan1<80000 then conc='level1';
  if loan2<80000 and home='new' then borrowcap = 'high';

  if last.id;
run;
```